# Newly added file requires .php extension, old files do not

Tags: php, smarty, http-status-code-404

I am taking over for a developer who left a website running a linux/apache on freebsd. I need to add a php page to the site. He used Smarty templates as well. I copied an existing php page and its corresponding template file.  Made changes to the template file and it created a compiled newfile.php.tpl file in the compiled directory.

All the php files can be accessed WITHOUT the .php and work fine.  If I refer to the newfile without .php I get a 404 error, with the .php it works fine.

.hataccess.  I have done a find on the the system and for this website, there does not appear to be a .htaccess file.  Even if there were the rest of the pages work fine without php extension.

Things I tried grep for the mod rewrite, i did a find on .htaccess, i rebooted.  So is there some cache i am missing or some other basic thing, apache, php?  I have put in about 12 hours on this.  The only thing i found remotely was a  url_rewriter.tags section in a phpcgi.html file.

Comment: Maybe MultiViews [Content Negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html) is what's causing the "rewrite"?

Comment: @rodneyrehm Thank you!  you indirectly led me to the lighttpd.conf file researching the above.  I found a fastcgi.server section and there is a url.rewrite-once = ( section of code with the specific pages for the site.  So I guess i will add my new page and assume all we be well.  thx again.

Answer (score 0):

Went to lighttpd.conf file researching @rodneyrehm sugg. I found a fastcgi.server section and there is a

```
url.rewrite-once = (
```

section of code with the specific pages for the site. So I added my new page and all is well.

Comment: consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking the "tick" or "check" icon next to it